# Dictionary / thesaurus for Cordova mobile apps

Tags: cordova

I am looking for a dictionary/thesaurus that I can use in a Cordova-based mobile application. Nothing too fancy, just a dictionary with words and short descriptions. The app will mainly be used offline, so I'm looking for something I can download and add to the app's resources.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction. All I've been able to find were finished dictionary apps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lookup Dictionary REST API. I found this: http://public.oed.com/subscriber-services/sru-service/ in the first search. Just a simple consumable REST API for free to use. Also, it's probably reliable to use since it's the official Oxford English Dictionary REST API)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I checked it out but it seems like I'll have to hit their server every time I want something from the dictionary? Or is there a way for me to download it? I don't want my app to depend on internet availability, nor a third party service over which I have no control.